# How to use Outlook Switch in Command Prompt from Form?

Tags: c#, string, command-line, outlook, switch-statement

I am trying to create a program that will create a new outlook message prepopulated with details using Outlook switches.

If I am in command prompt the following will successfully create a new blank message.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\OUTLOOK.EXE" /c ipm.note
```

I have found several posts here about how to use command prompt in c#, and have tried to get this same switch command to run from c# but it gives an error in the command prompt box that flashes: `ipm.note is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

I know ipm.note is correct for the switch, but apparently when passing it in the C# code it's missing something? Possibly an escape character? Here's my code that is in use.

`System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", "\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Office\\Office14\\OUTLOOK.EXE\" /c ipm.note");`

Also regarding this, I wanted to be able to use the @ symbol so I didn't have to escape each special character, but I don't know if you can use that and also add quotes inside a string, for example:

`string temp = @""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\OUTLOOK.EXE" /c ipm.note"`
In the above, the first set of quotes open and close then everything until the next set of quotes is not considered part of the string.

Recommendations on both of these situations are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the /c switch to cmd.exe as well. Try this:

```
Process.Start("cmd.exe", @"/c """"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\OUTLOOK.EXE"" /c ipm.note""");
```

However, it would actually be far better to just run outlook.exe directly and avoid a lot of the argument problems:

```
Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\OUTLOOK.EXE", "/c ipm.note");
```

In regard to your question about strings prefixed by the @ character, those strings are referred to as verbatim string literals. You can include a double quote inside one of these by using two double quotes together as I did in my code snippet.

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Fixed both issues. Thank you.

Comment: to add more switches do I have to add the switch at the beggining like you did with /c?: @"/c /m""""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\OUTLOOK.EXE"" /c ipm.note /m here@there.com"""; I'm not having much luck getting it to accept the to address switch.

Comment: You actually don't need to route the call through cmd.exe at all. Here's a simplified version that should work and is a little more straight forward: `Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\OUTLOOK.EXE", "/c ipm.note /m here@there.com");`

Comment: That is far better, thank you. Maybe append your original answer with that just for future people who find this.

Answer (score -2):

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15\OUTLOOK.EXE", @"/a C:\Users\Abu18saud.Abu18saud-PC.001\Documents\file_hml.pdf /m username@gmail.com /c ipm.note");
```

Comment: Please add some description like how this is a solution.